# Что делает setenv()?

Tags: c

Есть такой код:

```
void initializeSuplies(int paper)
{
char paperBuffer[10];
snprintf(paperBuffer, 10, "%d", paper);
setenv("PAPER", paperBuffer, 1);
}
```

Хочется понять что куда записывается и как?
Переменные окружения используются только в unix?

Можно по пунктам:

1. Вызывается функция initializeSuplies()
2. Создаётся массив paperBuffer
3. ?
4. ?

Comment: Учат их в ВУЗах dos'у, учат, а про переменные среды забывают. (Шютка) А вообще -- POSIX.1-2001

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Перемешки окружения есть и в **Windows**, если верить **MSDN** надо использовать для этого функции **_putenv, _wputenv** (для **unicode**) - подробнее смотрите в **MSDN**

Функция **setenv**() (**UNIX**) добавляет переменную окружения со значением находящимся в первом параметре, если ее не существует. Если переменная уже существует, то ее значение изменяется на заданное во втором параметре, при условии что флаг **overwrite** (третий параметр) не равен нулю, а если равен нулю, то значение переменной окружения не изменяется (т.е. такой вызов ни к чему не приведет). 
**setenv**() возвращает 0 при успешном завершении и -1 в других случаях.

Функция **unsetenv**() удаляет указанную переменную из окружения.

Comment: Опять же, при чём тут "уних"? Функция включена в стандарт. Если MS плевала на стандарты -- это уже другой вопрос.

mingw gcc у меня эту функцию в стандартной библиотеке на нашёл